# Shopify App - How to inject React in theme using App Proxy?

Tags: reactjs, shopify-app

**Overview**

I'm developing an app and I'd like to inject a widget in the store (the theme, not the app's front-end) coded with React. My app is already setup with NodeJS/Koa/ReactJS, all I need is to inject some code into the theme now.

I am aware that I can do this with a [Script Tag](https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/online-store/scripttag?api[version]=2020-04), however I'd still have to use vanilla JS to code what I want.

So I looked into [App Proxy](https://shopify.dev/tutorials/display-data-on-an-online-store-with-an-application-proxy-app-extension). I added a simple `index.html` file to my proxy path to test it out and it's returning 404.

**Question**

1. What type of files should be served within the App Proxy? Just `html`, `css` and `js` like a normal app?
2. Is this actually the best way to implement `React` in a store's theme?

Kindly help me if you can, I'm very confused with the documentation. I'll provide any additional information needed.

Thank you!

[image: Proxy App configuration]

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Unfortunately I did not, I ended up sticking with vanilla Javascript.

Comment: In messing around with it myself, that's what I figured. Thanks for the reply! Were you able to get app proxies to work? I'm diving through the docs currently but am really confused on the proper implementation. Literally just posted this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70488255/how-to-use-a-shopify-app-proxy-on-order-status-page

Comment: No problem! I was indeed, but it's been a while since I coded that app and I haven't been working with Shopify apps ever since then. I recall it was a pain to make it work, though. There were some odd bugs, like, if I changed the URL in the Shopify admin panel and saved it, it wouldn't work, I needed to refresh the page or something. Later on I found people talking about this bug in the Shopify community. There were things beyond my control messing up with the development, but the Shopify communtiy helped me enough to ensure I could finish the project.

Comment: Good deal, thank you again!